# pass arguments with called service

Tags: ros, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,
in my code I call a service that calls another service

```
bool srvCallback_my_switcher(cob_srvs::Trigger::Request &req, cob_srvs::Trigger::Response &res)

{   
    if (client.call(srv))
    {
        srv.request;
        stuff..

    res.success.data = true;
    return true;
}
```

is there a possibility to call the service srv with an argument for example a bool variable?
I would like the called service to differ whether variable is true or false.

Kindly guide :))

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197871/pass-arguments-with-called-service/) by [irgendeinGastname](https://answers.ros.org/users/20123/irgendeingastname/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should pass the variable you need by assign srv.request.[VariableName] = [true, false];, like you did in the response. Please also look at this tutorial:

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29

```
beginner_tutorials::AddTwoInts srv;
srv.request.a = atoll(argv[1]);
...
client.call(srv)
```

---

Originally posted by [Torsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/20838/torsten/) with karma: 111 on 2014-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1